# How to add a new task or process using java program?

Tags: java

I want to add a new process or new task to task manager using some java code. Can anyone helps me? Please tell me which command i have to use.

Comment: 1. Taskmanager is NOT under the control of application level programs. 2. You could use JNI / JNA to "try". 3. You could create a new process using ProcessBuilder. It will automatically get added to the task manager (if not already added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new process using ProcessBuilder class and that process automatically adds as new task in Task Manager.

for ex:

```
ProcessBuilder child =new  ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe","");
child.start();
```

Using ProcessBuilder I open a notepad, as soon as it opens you can view `notepad.exe` task in your Task Manager.